# Remove slash between action and querystring (like how SO's search behaves)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url, query-string, slash

I've just added some search functionality to a project of mine which is working correctly.  Having just used the *SO search*, I realised there is one tiny detail which I prefer to my own search and I became curious as to how it is achieved being as I'm also using **MVC 3** and **Razor** for my site.

If I search *SO*, I'll end up with a URL such as:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=foo
```

However, searching my own application results in:

```
http://example.com/posts/search/?searchTerms=foo
```

Notice the `/` between `search` and `?`.  Although this is purely cosmetic, how can I remove that from the URL so it ends up as:

```
http://example.com/posts/search?searchTerms=foo
```

This is my search route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SearchPosts",
    "posts/search/{*searchTerms}",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "Search", searchTerms = "" }
);
```

I've tried removing the slash from the route but that gave an error.  I also tried adding in a `?` instead of the slash but that also gave an error.  Would anyone be kind enough to solve this mystery for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, when the `searchTerms` can be null-or-emptyString, that is not necessary to put it in `mapRoute`. And when you try to create a link by `Html.ActionLink` or `Html.RouteLink`, and pass a `searchTerms` parameter to it, it will create the `searchTerms` as a query-string without any slashes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "SearchPosts",
    "posts/search",
    new { controller = "Posts", action = "Search"
    /* , searchTerms = "" (this is not necessary really) */ }
);
```

and in Razor:

```
// for links:
// @Html.RouteLink(string linkText, string routeName, object routeValues);
@Html.RouteLink("Search", "SearchPosts", new { searchTerms = "your-search-term" });
// on click will go to:
// example.com/posts/search?searchTerms=your-search-term
// by a GET command
```

---

```
// or for forms:
// @Html.BeginRouteForm(string routeName, FormMethod method)
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchPosts", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.TextBox("searchTerms")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

    // on submit will go to:
    // example.com/posts/search?searchTerms=*anything that may searchTerms-textbox contains*
    // by a GET command

}
```

and in controller:

```
public class PostsController : Controller {
    public ActionResult Search(string searchTerms){
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerms)) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah so simple.  That cleared up the other question I had regarding optional parameters.  Great answer, thank you. :)